# How does a CSplitterWnd and two different views handle UPDATE_COMMAND_UI for the menu/toolbar

Tags: mfc, toolbar

I took an existing single view and changed it to a `CSplitterWnd` to add a new split view of a new `CTreeView` and the old `CListView`.

How is the toolbar update supposed to work with the use of `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` so when THE focus is in one view vs. the other, the toolbar options are enabled/disabled properly (some toolbar buttons are shared).

Comment: Presumably, your derived view class has some member(s) that allow you to tell which 'type' it is. You can test that/those members in the `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler. Maybe show us some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out MFC tries the active view first, then moves up to the mainframe and even document and app.  So you can handle the `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` wherever it would make the most since.